# Remaining IPs in a range/CIDR

Tags: go, network-programming

I would like to find the remaining IPs in a range (CIDR).
For example:

```
prefixLen, bits := n.Mask.Size()
return 1 << (uint64(bits) - uint64(prefixLen)), nil
```

This return the # of IPs in the range where `n` is `*net.IPNet`.
But say if I have few addresses that are already given out and want to know how many are left 'starting' from some  IP addresses, how can I do it?

Comment: I only have the last address that is given out. For eg: for 192.168.2.0/20, you can get 4096 addresses (including net and broadcast address). I'm not tracking how many are given out but I do have what is the latest that is given out. That happens to be for eg: 192.168.2.9 (which means 7 usable IPs are in given out). So outstanding free IPs are 4094-7 = 4087. Basically I want remaining IPs within the range.

Comment: You are supposed to mark the answer that solves your question as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

Here's something you could do

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net"

)
func inet_aton(ip string) uint32 {
var rv uint32
b := net.ParseIP(ip).To4()
rv=uint32(b[0]) << 24
rv=rv+uint32(b[1]) << 16
rv=rv+uint32(b[2]) << 8
rv=rv+uint32(b[3])
return rv
}

func main() {
    start := inet_aton("192.168.0.1")   //192.168.2.0/20 start
    fin := inet_aton("192.168.15.255")  //ditto end
    here := inet_aton("192.168.15.248") //current allocation

    fmt.Printf("you have %d remaining\n",(fin-start) - (here-start))
}
```

Comment: Thanks much.! I did not even know inet_aton() can be used.

Comment: I think it's one of those things that are obvious when you see it.  IP addresses are really unsigned 4-byte ints.  So they are equivalent to numbers and operations like this are trivial

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to do it that works for both IPv4 and IPv6 using the [IPAddress Go library](https://seancfoley.github.io/IPAddress/).  Disclaimer: I am the project manager.

```golang
func remaining(cidr string) (used, remaining, total *big.Int) {
    cidrStr := ipaddr.NewIPAddressString(cidr)
    cidrBlock := cidrStr.GetAddress().ToPrefixBlock()
    host := cidrStr.GetHostAddress()
    used = new(big.Int).Sub(host.GetValue(), cidrBlock.GetValue())
    remaining = new(big.Int).Sub(cidrBlock.GetUpperValue(), host.GetValue())
    total = cidrBlock.GetCount()
    fmt.Printf("\nHost %s is address number %d of %d addresses in block %s.\n"+
        "There remains %d addresses.\n", host, used, total, cidrBlock,
        remaining)
    return
}
```

If you want to stick with IPv4, then you can replace big.Int with unsigned int types.

```golang
func remainingIPv4(cidr string) (used, remaining uint32, total uint64) {
    cidrStr := ipaddr.NewIPAddressString(cidr)
    cidrBlock := cidrStr.GetAddress().ToPrefixBlock().ToIPv4()
    host := cidrStr.GetHostAddress().ToIPv4()
    used = host.Uint32Value() - cidrBlock.Uint32Value()
    remaining = cidrBlock.UpperUint32Value() - host.Uint32Value()
    total = cidrBlock.GetIPv4Count()
    fmt.Printf("\nHost %s is address number %d of %d addresses in block %s.\n"+
        "There remains %d addresses.\n", host, used, total, cidrBlock,
        remaining)
    return
}
```

Example:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/seancfoley/ipaddress-go/ipaddr"
    "math/big"
)

func main() {
    remaining("192.168.2.0/20")
    remaining("2001:0db8:85a3::8a2e:0370:7334/64")

    remainingIPv4("192.168.2.0/20")
}
```

Example output:

```
Host 192.168.2.0 is address number 512 of 4096 addresses in block 192.168.0.0/20.
There remains 3583 addresses.

Host 2001:db8:85a3::8a2e:370:7334 is address number 151930230829876 of 18446744073709551616 addresses in block 2001:db8:85a3::/64.
There remains 18446592143478721739 addresses.

Host 192.168.2.0 is address number 512 of 4096 addresses in block 192.168.0.0/20.
There remains 3583 addresses.
```